# WAS Liberty: DEV and UAT Configuration

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am wondering what is the best way to configure an WAS Liberty installation, allowing to to switch from a DEV environment configuration to an UAT(testing)  environment configuration dynamically.

To elaborate, we have a similar setup with our glassfish servers, we simply configure system properties for both in the Glassfish console. For example

```
hostname.uat="some uat value"
hostname.dev="some dev value"
```

Dropping the "**.uat**" or "**.dev**" in the system property configuration in Glassfish makes that property active. In Glassfish, this can be done dynamically and while the application is running (no need to reboot).

Is there or can someone elaborate how I could achieve a similar setup in WAS Liberty?

Thank-you kindly

Comment: do you want this property to switch between a dev and a test version of Liberty?  or a dev and test version of some app you are writing?

Comment: @aguibert there is only one application ever deployed. The application merely reads system properties via system properties configuration set within glassfish. These properties can be changed dynamically, and read by the deployed application allowing the app to communicate to dev or uat .

Comment: ok, so you have 1 copy of your application and 1 instance of the server, but you want to be able to dynamically change the server configuration?  To do that on Liberty you could keep 2 different copies of the server.xml and swap out the files based on which configuration you want to work with.  All the config for a Liberty server can be done in a single server.xml file.

Comment: @aguibert Thank-you thus far. Yes 1 copy and 1 server instance. I presently have my properties configured in a server.env file. The properties are name/value pairs and I'm am not sure that I cna place them within the server.xml since it is, an xml file. For example, here is one properties admin.email=dev.admin@domain.com, the same property for uat is admin.email=uat.admin@domain.com. How can a server.xml read name/value pairs etc?

Comment: ah, you want to set environment variables.  You want the `server.env` file then.  I've updated my answer with how to do that.

Comment: @aguibert Thanks for the feedback thus far. So much of what you posted I have already done. I guess what I would like to know is, is it possible to swap server.env file dynamically without having to restart an application?For example, imagine two server.env files, server.env.uat and server.env.dev .. making one of them active by renaming it to simply server.env and swaping accordingly when I want the application to point to the other (uat/dev) etc?

Comment: No, there is currently no mechanism to dynamically change env vars. The closest thing would be using `server.env`, which gets loaded at server start time. If you want it to be dynamic, you could write a simple helper method to read a .properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `server.env` file in two possible places:
 
 `${wlp.install.dir}/etc/server.env` (properties are applied to all servers) or 
 `${server.config.dir}/server.env` (properties applied only to one server)
and specify any environment variables in that file.

For example:

```
# Specify properties and values
admin.email=dev.admin@domain.com
admin.email.uat=uat.admin@domain.com
```

To access these properties in an application environment (such as a Servlet) do the following:

```
System.getenv("admin.email"); // returns "dev.admin@domain.com"
```

Other useful properties can be specified in the `server.env` file as well such as `JAVA_HOME`, `WLP_USER_DIR`, `WLP_OUTPUT_DIR`, and `WLP_DEBUG_ADDRESS`.

For IBM's full doc on this, see: 
[Customizing the Liberty Environment](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html).

Comment: Is server.env monitored/reloaded?

Comment: nope, server.env is only loaded at server start time

Comment: I ahve reserched, and you can change the value of a property in the Liberty server.xml (or included file) and the change is dynamic. Does anyone know if there is a way to define user-defined properties within the server.xml that can later be read as system properties within the applications?

Comment: It's true that server.xml configuration elements are responsive to dynamic changes.  There are not any server.xml elements that can be read by a user application though.

Comment: So is it fair to say that, the IBM Liberty cannot perform the same setup as Glassfish? That is, there is no way of creating dynamic system properties?

Comment: Not using this approach.  Your alternatives options are using the VariableRegistry SPI in a user feature, or if you have application monitoring turned on you could create a file in your application to house the properties.  Using the latter approach, whenever the file is changed then your webapp would be reloaded (but not necessarily restarted).

Answer (score 0):

What we do is generate the Liberty server with Ansible, where the variables can be added to an ansible inventory based on environment.

So, our deployments essentially drop and recreate the Liberty server by using ansible templates and roles to stamp it out as needed.

Lastly, we make use of Hasicorp Vault (you can also use ansible-vault) for credentials or secrets at deploy time to fetch credentials. This is then injected into Ansible as JSON and used to stamp out the server.xml and other related configuration files.